# Fourier Transform of integral

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform

Suppose we have a Fourier pair of 
$f(t)={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(w)e^{-iwt}dw$ and $F(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{iwt}dt.$

How can we prove the following pair?
$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t g(\tau) d\tau $ and $F(w)=G(w)/iw+\pi G(0)\delta(w),$ where $\delta$ is a delta function.

Comment: Do you know the Fourier transform of the step function?

Comment: I am afraid I don't

Comment: @Ray In general, we cannot assign meaning to $\mathscr{F}\{u*g\}$. 

For example, if $g(t)=u(t)$, then $u*u=tu(t)$.  I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825297/fourier-transform-of-t-ht/2825495#2825495) that in  distribution 

$$\mathscr{F}\{ u*u\}=\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)+i\pi \delta'(\omega)\tag1$$

where $\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)$ is the distributional derivative of $\text{PV}\left(\frac1{\omega}\right)$.

The right-hand side is obviously ***not*** equal to $\pi G(\omega)\delta(\omega)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{G(\omega)}{i\omega}\right)$.

Comment: @Ray I'm uncertain whether you had a chance to read the comment I left.  Please let me know if you have.

Answer (score 10):

The step function 
$$u(t)=\begin{cases}
1,& t\ge0\\
0,& t<0
\end{cases}$$
has the Fourier transform $$U(\omega)=\frac{1}{i\omega}+\pi\delta(\omega)$$
I leave it to you to find out how (it is not difficult!).

Now considering the definition of convolution, we can write the given integral as follows:

$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t g(\tau) \mathrm d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(\tau)u(t-\tau) \mathrm d\tau=g(t)*u(t)$$

Using the convolution theorem, we have $F(\omega)=G(\omega)U(\omega)$. That is

$$F(\omega)=\frac{G(\omega)}{i\omega}+\pi G(\omega)\delta(\omega)$$
and since $\delta(\omega)$ is only nonzero at $\omega=0$, it simplifies to

$$F(\omega)=\frac{G(\omega)}{i\omega}+\pi G(0)\delta(\omega)$$

Comment: What about if $f(t)=\int_{t}^{\infty}g(\tau) d\tau$ ?

Comment: In such case $$f(t)=\int_t^{\infty} g(\tau) \mathrm d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(\tau)u(\tau-t) \mathrm d\tau=g(t)*u(-t)$$ and $F(\omega)=G(\omega)U(-\omega)=\frac{G(\omega)}{-i\omega}+\pi G(0)\delta(\omega)$

Comment: @msm In general, we cannot assign meaning to $\mathscr{F}\{u*g\}$. 

For example, if $g(t)=u(t)$, then $u*u=tu(t)$.  I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825297/fourier-transform-of-t-ht/2825495#2825495) that in  distribution 

$$\mathscr{F}\{ u*u\}=\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)+i\pi \delta'(\omega)\tag1$$

where $\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)$ is the distributional derivative of $\text{PV}\left(\frac1{\omega}\right)$.

The right-hand side is obviously ***not*** equal to $\pi G(\omega)\delta(\omega)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{G(\omega)}{i\omega}\right)$.

Comment: @msm I'm uncertain whether you had a chance to read the comment I left.  Please let me know if you have.