# Why is the characteristic function of the sign function $2i/t$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, dirac-delta, characteristic-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

A book I'm reading says:

> Let $\theta(x)$ be the Heaviside function... Since $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=2\theta(x)-1$, its characteristic function will be:
> $$\chi_{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}(t)=\frac{2i}{t}$$

I understand why $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=2\theta(x)-1$, but I don't follow the claim about the characteristic function. If the CDF of $X$ is the Heaviside function, then $X$ is a.s. zero, and the sign of $X$ is a.s. zero, and the characteristic of a random variable that is a.s. zero is $1$. How does $2i/t$ come into it?

Comment: What is the characteristic fucntion of other function?

Comment: What other function? No other function is mentioned. From the context, there is a suggestion that we're dealing with a situation "with finite mean but infinite variance".

Comment: From the title: "The characteristic function of the sign function"

Comment: I'm sorry; I just meant the characteristic function of $sgn(x)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726611/fourier-transform-of-signum-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word characteristic function is misleading.

Here $\theta(x)$ is not the CDF of a random variable, we are looking at the Fourier transform of $\theta(x)$ not of $d\theta(x)=\delta(x)dx$.

This Fourier transform exists only in the sense of distributions, it will be $PV(i/t)+\pi \delta(t)$ ($PV$ for principal value).

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts viz. [Riemann–Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties),$$\int_{\Bbb R}e^{itx}\operatorname{sgn}x\mathrm dx=-\frac{1}{it}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{itx}2\delta(x)\mathrm dx=\frac{2i}{t},$$but this still requires the question to intend convergence in a distributional sense.