# Circumference of a circle using integral representation of Dirac delta

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am trying to obtain the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ in a rather complex way because I am practising with the integral representation of the Dirac delta. Let me refer to the circle as $C$ and let me write the expression to be computed as
$$
\int_C dx dy = \int \int \delta(x^2+y^2 - r^2) || \nabla (x^2+y^2 - r^2) || dx dy \\
= 2r \int \int \delta(x^2+y^2 - r^2) dx dy .\tag{1}
$$
I know that the last integral evaluates to $\pi$, which can be seen easily after changing to polar coordinates. However, I want to stick to Cartesian coordinates and use that
$$
\delta(x^2 + y^2 - r^2) = \int \frac{d \omega}{2 \pi} {\rm{e}}^{i\omega (x^2 + y^2 - r^2)}.\tag{2}
$$
Then the double integral can be rewritten as
$$
 \int \int \delta(x^2+y^2 - r^2) dx dy =    \int \frac{d \omega}{2 \pi}  \int \int {\rm{e}}^{i\omega (x^2 + y^2 - r^2)} dx dy.\tag{3}
$$
And now we can perform the Gaussian integral over $x$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx {\rm{e}}^{i\omega x^2}  = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{- i \omega}}.\tag{4}
$$
And similarly over $y$. Therefore we arrive at
$$
 \int \int \delta(x^2+y^2 - r^2) dx dy = \frac{1}{2} \int {d \omega} \frac{{\rm{e}}^{-i\omega r^2}}{(-i \omega)}.\tag{5} 
$$
Then we can identify the integral as the inverse Fourier transform ($\mathcal{F}^{-1}()$) of the function $i/\omega$ evaluated at $r^2$ (and multiplied by the prefactor $\sqrt{2 \pi}$), i.e.
$$
 \int \int \delta(x^2+y^2 - r^2) dx dy = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{i}{\omega} \right)\right)_{r^2} \\
 = \frac{\pi}{2} \Theta(r^2) \\
= \frac{\pi}{2}.\tag{6}
$$
Where $\Theta()$ refers to the Heaviside function. As you can see, I am off of the correct result by a factor of 1/2.

Comment: Can you please say a few lines as to why $|| \nabla (x^2+y^2 - r^2) ||$ term appears in the first equation ( for my understanding )?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Eq. (4) is ill-defined if $\omega=0$. We can regularize eq. (4) as a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x~ e^{(i\omega-0^+) x^2}  
~=~\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{0^+- i \omega}},\tag{4'} $$
so that eq. (3) becomes
$$\begin{align}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~ \delta(x^2+y^2 - r^2)  
~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{2 \pi}  \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~ e^{i\omega (x^2 + y^2 - r^2)}\cr
~\stackrel{(4')}{=}~& \int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{2 \pi}  \frac{\pi}{0^+- i \omega}  e^{-i\omega  r^2}\cr
~=~& \frac{i}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{\omega+i0^+}  e^{-i\omega  r^2}\cr
~=~& \frac{i}{2} (-2\pi i) \Theta(r^2)\cr
~=~& \pi\Theta(r^2),  
\end{align} \tag{3'}$$
where we closed the $\omega$-contour in the lower (upper) $\omega$-plane if $r^2>0$ ($r^2<0$), respectively.

Comment: Many thanks @Qmechanic! That makes sense. One question, though: why is it needed to introduce the regularization (eq. (4'))? Is the integral not well defined as it stands?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Another question: is it wrong to see my equation (5) as an inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: Eqs. (5)-(6) seem to be related to [Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3726611/11127) of ${\rm PV}\frac{1}{\omega}$ versus ${\rm sgn}(r^2)$.